# Sharepoint and Bing Maps

Tags: sharepoint-online, geolocation

I'm having some issues with Bing Maps and Sharepoint. I'm trying to create an interactive map that plots locations and details a how much it would cost to transport a vehicle to that location. I need this to be edited by certain members of my team, and I'd like them to be able to pick a point on the map and it adds that to the Sharepoint list database.

Currently i'm having issues with map views as it won't display as a map view unless i create a Web Part Page. But also to get this working I have to manually add the Geo Locations Long and Lat tags for every location which isn't very user friendly.

Is there anyway to that a user can enter the address and the geo-tags are populated from the address? or am I am going about it the wrong way ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create SPFx client side webpart. SPFx webpart can be made configurable as webpart property. Or you can create a section in main webpart to get inputs from users and then display map location accordingly.

There is npm bing map npm package you can use, this can be used with SPFx webpart according to our need.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bingmaps